# Passing Oauth tokens to the GA 4 .net library google.analytics.data.v1Beta

Tags: .net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have a GA UA implementation that utilises oAuth tokens to query GA UA to retrieve reports from various users accounts (our system deals with many clients, so we cannot have Service Accounts).

I am trying to set the same up for GA4. However, the .net library provided by Google is very lacking in documentation and seems to only promote Service Accounts.

Has anyone had any luck connecting to GA4 with the library with OAuth tokens?

nuget package
Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta(2.0.0-beta03)

Previously for GA UA you could do something like this

```
var analyticsService = new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    ApplicationName = _config["GoogleAD:ProjectId"],
    HttpClientInitializer = cuc
 });
```

The *HttpClientInitializer* is a custom class that inherits from *IHttpExecuteInterceptor, IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer*

It assigns the auth token to the Authorization header.

I am trying to do something similar for GA4 but not having much luck

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by changing a couple of things.

NOTE: I handle token refresh via a central API we have so this way would not work for you if you have to refresh access tokens.

CustomUserCredential Class

```
public class CustomUserCredential : ICredential, IHttpExecuteInterceptor
{
    private string _accessToken;

    public CustomUserCredential(string accessToken)
    {
        _accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public Task<string> GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(string authUri = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_accessToken);
    }

    public void Initialize(ConfigurableHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        httpClient.MessageHandler.ExecuteInterceptors.Add(this);
    }

    public async Task InterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);
    }
}
```

---

Usage

```
var customUserCred = new CustomerUserCredential("[Access_Token]");

var client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClientBuilder
{
      GrpcAdapter = RestGrpcAdapter.Default,
      Credential = customUserCred
}.Build();
```